# How to be a good sniper?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I recently bought Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3 and with my most loved classes I end up having a K:D ratio of 2:1 or 3:1 almost every game. But when it comes to playing as a sniper I just get to 1:1 ratios.

I usually play a bit kamikaze style, much running, precise shooting and always surprising the enemy. When trying to play as a sniper (and I really like being a sniper) I end up getting shot half of the time. Even when I try to lay down my kamikaze intentions and look for a good spot I either end up laying somewhere and nobody comes across my way or I am kind of in the middle of a world war. Also the enemies always seem to see me very quickly.

My aiming besides that is actually pretty good by the way.

Is it just my incapability of finding the right spot for hiding? Are there some special things I have to pay attention to?

Comment: I can't offer any specific tips as I stopped playing MW3 over a year ago, but in general try to move around a bit.  If you spend a minute in a spot and see no one, then it's time to move.  In general, you should learn the spawns and try to get a general idea of where the other team is spawning, and the routes they will be taking to your spawn.  Find some good cover, preferably at a slight angle from their approach and start picking them off.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good already. Still it feels that some of the MW3 maps have stupid spawn areas. Sometimes you kinda see noone if you don't move enough and sometimes you have no calm for sniping because the enemies spawn right next to you. But thanks again for the answer.

Comment: yeah when I quit the spawns were pretty bad, a problem that seems to be pretty big problem for the franchise in recent years.  I might also recommend playing demolition, as usually you'll spawn on one side or the other and this can help you learn the maps/spots a little better without constant worry of having the enemy spawn behind you.

Comment: That a good idea! I am stuck on the Team Deathmatch mode as almost everyone I guess, definitely gonna take a look at that! Thanks :)

Comment: Not to try and flame, but CoD in general is not designed for real 'sniping'. You'll have to move, need to have a spot with few access points, good sight lines. There just aren't many of these spots in most MW3 maps.

Comment: Yeah that's so right, but I tried it again yesterday with Turbo's tips and it went better for sure. Is it a off-topic question when I ask you about battlefield 3 and it's design for sniping?

Comment: The snark in me wants to say "quickscope". The pragmatist though says LEARN to quickscope; due to the constant CQB of the CoD series, knowing how to accurately nail a guy when he jumps around a corner in your face will save your butt. As a poor alternative to that, get real cozy with your secondary weapon.

Answer (score 2):

Look some youtube videos to know how to setup a real good sniper class.

If you want to learn quickscope, try it maybe with friends in private matches.

Or stick a cellotape in the middle of your screen and make a point on this tape where your scope is. This is a small trick to know where you will shoot before you scope.
And then with the time it comes. Then you will going to be a CoD-Sniper

Comment: I laughed about this one. Sry for late reply

Answer (score 1):

Using an ACOG attachment made my accuracy better when quick scoping. Going back to the normal scope increased my accuracy as well.

Comment: ACOG attachment for a overall starter may be useful, but for me I got much better using the normal scope. Guess it also depends on the map you are playing on.

Answer (score 1):

You should practice your shooting on domination or with a buddy. Don't try and play how you would with a red gun and don't try to camp either as it may frustrate you when there's no one around. My advice would be to work your way around the outside of the map  not the inside because then you would be fully exposed to the enemies. Best thing to do is not care about what other people think of your skills because as you get more confident in your shot, you'll be able to surprise the enemy team more often.

Answer (score 1):

Using a single-fire weapon is the closest thing to a sniper, so if you can get good with that might help but I used the MSR out of all of the snipers and just aiming down sight and if your trying to quick-scope use slight of hand, quickdraw, and sit-rep or ninja. (thats what I used)

Answer (score 0):

The fist thing you have to do is set up your sniper class. You can use any sniper you are comfortable with.

Then you have to pick a good playlist. Don't play domination because players always run around in groups. You can improve your skills in drop zone.

After that you want to pick a good spot! Walk around the borders of the map and don't rush with a sniper!

You will need confidence. The last and important thing is to not get angry.

Answer (score 0):

Try staying behind your team but don't camp it's hard to explain but as soon as you kill something move forward a bit wait and again and again or you can find a good spot where you can sit and the enemy team will pour out the side. As you do this stick with your team because you don't want the spawns switching. Another good tip is to check your minimap once every while. If you are waiting some where stay unscoped unless you know someone is gonna come out, if you don't then stay unscoped because it will give you more vision and let you see more and then as soon as someone comes into view quickly aim and fire. That's how I snipe!

Answer (score -1):

Try to shoot as fast as possible i mean dont steady aim for a long time . If the sot missed it doesnt matter but snipe fast . Its my Secret of a good sniper : ) and keep doing stuffs like jumping sitting etc to increase your speed